How to display the label text when we hover over the labels on X or Y axes?
I am currently working on a React project that is using ChartJS to generate charts based on the data gathered from the database. Recently I found an issue when the labels are too long,the chart will get pushed to the side. To overcome this I truncated the names of labels on the X and Y axes but when we hover over the graph the entire label will be visible. (attached the image for reference)
Image of chart from my app
Here is my Chart component thatI'm currently using
<Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
  {chartType === "Horizontal" && (
    <CreateChart
      type="Bar"
      data={[
        {
          alias: "1",
          x: x,
          y: y,
          direction: "row",
        },
      ]}
    />
  )}
  {chartType === "Vertical" && (
    <CreateChart
      type="Bar"
      data={[
        {
          alias: "1",
          x: x,
          y: y,
          direction: "column",
        },
      ]}
    />
  )}
  {chartType === "Pie" && (
    <CreateChart
      type="Pie"
      data={[
        {
          alias: "1",
          x: x,
          y: y,
        },
      ]}
    />
  )}
  {chartType === "Bubble" && (
    <CreateChart
      type="Bubble"
      data={[
        {
          alias: "1",
          x: x,
          y: y,
          r: r,
          bubbleData: bubbleData,
        },
      ]}
    />
  )}
</Box>;

What I want to implement is when I hover over the labels that are present on the axes either X or Y, the name of the label should be displayed in a tooltip.
I've implemented some modifications to the options prop that I found in a post here
options = {{
  tooltips: {
    mode: "index",
    intersect: false,
  },
  hover: {
    mode: "index",
    intersect: false,
  },
}};

